# Can anyone identify this elderly tandem from the badge (pictured)

Tags: vintage, tandems

[image: Picture of badge - is it some kind of bird or dragon?]

This is a tandem which I bought at least 20 years ago and it was far from new then.  I have absolutely no idea who made it.  This badge looks a bit like a bird or perhaps a dragon?

Comment: Looks like a Raleigh headbadge.

Comment: If you show us a bit more of the bike's frame then we can make some more comments.   All I can tell from that is it's a steel frame and has a significant rust issue.  May not be safe to ride at all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's the remnants of a Raleigh headbadge.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

and it's a bird yes, it's a herron.
If you would like an idea of when the bike was manufactured, you might be lucky to still have the original Sturmey Archer hub, it is stamped to give you an idea of the year manufactured.  often the bikes are about the same age.

enjoy.